# show 2 images on a single tile along with some text that keeps on changing

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-8

I am Using Telerik RAD Tools for Windows 8. 
I want to use a Tile type interface , actually I Want to show 2 images on a single tile along with some text that keeps on changing . I am confused which tile to use for this as there are so many options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following tutorial will help you out.

http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/09/introduction-to-telerik-radslidehubtile-control-for-windows-8-store-application.html

This will give you how to use the RadSlideHubTile control